# circlepack plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I am trying to make a **`circlepack`** plot out of my data frame but I haven't been successful.

I want to for each draw a circle for each individual, e.g. S003 with type of class(es) belonging to that individual. size indicates number of time each class for each individual has occurred.

Been trying with these two threads  [how to use circle pack layout in ggraph library in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739749/how-to-use-circle-pack-layout-in-ggraph-library-in-r) and  https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/315-hide-first-level-in-circle-packing/ but couldn't do it.

```
test <- data.frame(individual = c("S003", "S003", "S004", "S004","S004", "S009", "S009", 
                                  "S016", "S016", "S016", "S016", "S025", "S025", "S027",
                                  "S027", "S035", "S035", "S035", "S035", "S036", "S036", 
                                  "S036", "S042", "S042", "S042", "S042" , "S042", "S042",
                                  "S043", "S043", "S043", "S045", "S045", "S045", "S045", 
                                  "S045", "S045", "S047" , "S047", "S047", "S047", "S047"),
                   class = c("NMF1", "NMF1", "NMF1", "NMF3", "NMF3", "NMF4", "NMF2", 
                             "NMF3", "NMF3", "NMF3" ,"NMF2", "NMF4", "NMF2", "NMF3", 
                             "NMF1", "NMF4", "NMF2", "NMF4", "NMF4", "NMF1", "NMF1", 
                             "NMF1", "NMF3", "NMF4", "NMF4", "NMF4", "NMF4", "NMF4", 
                             "NMF2", "NMF3", "NMF3" ,"NMF2", "NMF2", "NMF3", "NMF1", 
                             "NMF2", "NMF2", "NMF2", "NMF2", "NMF4", "NMF2", "NMF2"), 
                   count= c("2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1",
                            "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "5",
                            "5", "5", "5", "5", "1", "2" , "2", "4", "4", "1", "1", "4",
                            "4", "4", "4", "1", "4", "4"))

vertices <- test %>% distinct(class, count)
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(test, vertices = vertices)
```

> ```
> Error in graph_from_data_frame(test, vertices = vertices) : 
>   Duplicate vertex names
> ```